# Filling in compose the free space between two Text with dot character?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have this code:

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    Text(
        text = titleSummary,
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 24.dp)
            .padding(start = 16.dp)
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
    
        Text(
            text = priceOrBonusText,
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            textDecoration = TextDecoration.LineThrough,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = 24.dp)
                .padding(end = 4.dp)
        )
}
```

Now I have here to fill the space - Spacer with a width of 1f.
How can Spacer instead make padding from the first Text to the second Text as a dot character "." ? It is necessary to fill the entire width with dots from one element to the second

Example:

```
Text ............................... Text
```

**UPD:**
it turned out to draw points using `Canvas`, but in the end the resulting "points" fly up. how can I center them on the bottom border of `Text` elements?

```
Canvas(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(horizontal = 4.dp)
        .padding(bottom = 6.dp)
        .align(Alignment.Bottom)
        .weight(1f)
) {
    renderingDots()
}
```

```
private fun DrawScope.renderingDots() {
    val dotRadius = 1.dp.toPx()
    val dotSpacing = 2.dp.toPx()
    val dotColor = Color(0xFF2F2F2F)

    val dotCount = (size.width / (dotRadius * 2 + dotSpacing)).toInt()

    repeat(dotCount) { index ->
        val dotX = (index * (dotRadius * 2 + dotSpacing)) + dotRadius
        drawCircle(
            dotColor,
            radius = dotRadius,
            center = Offset(dotX, size.height / 2)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using `TextMeasurere()`.

[image]

When the start text or the end text or both is very long, the text overflows to the next line. How to handle this scenario is not given in the question, I can modify accordingly if this is not the expectation.

**Driver code**

```
@Composable
fun DotBetweenTextDemo() {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(32.dp),
    ) {
        DotBetweenTextUI(
            start = "Start",
            end = "End",
        )
        DotBetweenTextUI(
            start = "",
            end = "",
        )
        DotBetweenTextUI(
            start = "Start with long text",
            end = "End with long text",
        )
        DotBetweenTextUI(
            start = "Start with very very very very very long text",
            end = "End with long text",
        )
        DotBetweenTextUI(
            start = "Start with long text",
            end = "End with very very very very very very long text",
        )
        DotBetweenTextUI(
            start = "Start with very very very very very long text",
            end = "End with very very very very very very long text",
        )
    }
}
```

**Component code**

```
@Composable
private fun DotBetweenTextUI(
    start: String,
    end: String,
) {
    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
    ) {
        val composableWidth = maxWidth
        val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()

        val startTextStartPadding = 16.dp
        val startTextEndPadding = 0.dp
        val endTextStartPadding = 0.dp
        val endTextEndPadding = 4.dp

        val textStyle = TextStyle(
            fontSize = 16.sp,
        )

        val startWidth = textMeasurer.measure(
            text = start,
            style = textStyle,
        ).size.width.pxToDp()
        val endWidth = textMeasurer.measure(
            text = end,
            style = textStyle,
        ).size.width.pxToDp()
        val dotWidth = textMeasurer.measure(
            text = ".",
            style = textStyle,
        ).size.width.pxToDp()


        val composableWidthInFloat = floor(composableWidth.value)
        val startAndEndComposableWidthWithPadding = (startWidth.value) + (endWidth.value) +
                (startTextStartPadding.value) + (startTextEndPadding.value) +
                (endTextStartPadding.value) + (endTextEndPadding.value)

        val calculatedNumberOfDots =
            ((composableWidthInFloat - startAndEndComposableWidthWithPadding) / dotWidth.value).toInt()
        val numberOfDots = if (calculatedNumberOfDots < 0) {
            0
        } else {
            calculatedNumberOfDots
        }
        val dotText = ".".repeat(numberOfDots)

        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = start,
                style = textStyle,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(
                        start = startTextStartPadding,
                        end = startTextEndPadding,
                    )
            )
            Text(
                text = dotText,
                style = textStyle,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1F),
            )
            Text(
                text = end,
                style = textStyle,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(
                        start = endTextStartPadding,
                        end = endTextEndPadding,
                    )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the only one, between the right text (end) - there may be another one that appears by a boolean condition. Can you tell me how to fit it into this construction and calculate the indents for it?

Comment: If the additional Composable has a fixed size when it appears, you can add that as well similar to how padding is added for these two texts.